# What are the common pitfalls (and things to test) when building timezone aware apps?

Tags: language-agnostic, timezone

I am building a timzone aware app. What are the common (and not so common) scenarios I should test for?

Only corner case I can think of is DST, but I am sure I am missing a bunch.

Comment: paging Jon Skeet, come in Jon Skeet....

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

- Timezones are timeseries: By this I mean if you take the local time of some instant and store it somewhere then you're using today's timezone information.  By tomorrow this information may have changed and the stored instant may be interpreted differently.  To solve this consider storing the timezone information at hand with the event or instant you want to describe.
- Dates and times are observations: By this I mean you can encode an instant in local time regardless of the timezone in effect at that instant, and do conversions at the time of observation.  2am on the 1st of January might be 4 days and 3 hours ahead of some reference point today.  But at 2am on the 1st of January the very same reference point might appear only to be 4 days and 2 hours ago.  So you have to keep an eye out when converting between elapsed time between reference points at different times.  In particular, if you set a timer (in `N` seconds) you might need to recalculate if it still matches the event from time to time.
- Timezones are regional: By this I mean you can't just treat all datetimes with the same timezone offset as equal.  Especially DST-observing places in the Northern and Southern hemisphere may coincide for a while during the year while they are completely out of sync during the rest of the year.
- Dates and times specified in local time need not exist or can exist more than once.  You gave the DST example, at the time of a DST switch backwards times in between occur twice, once before the switch and once afterwards, so you may need a flag for that.  Similarly, a DST switch forward skips times.  DST, however is not the only example.  Some regions near the international date line decided to be left or right of it, and as a result there's either a whole day missing or a whole day repeated twice.